# Where should I put textAngular's toolbar customizations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text-editor, angular-ui

I need to be able to change the icons, the classes and the texts of the toolbar.

I found this page https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Setting-Defaults that explains how to change the defaults, but I'm unsure of the best place to put the code.

Should I put it in:

- a directive for better organization?
- a new "module" and then include it?
- or do I have to place it in the main config in app.js (which sucks for organization)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yeah, all the examples on the github/wiki page do the modifications in `app.config`. I'd be interested to know if you found a solution you liked better

Answer (score 0):

It's good to include it as a separate module and then include it. But it would be beeter to inject it in the main config app.js and it will be callable in all the modules in the angularjs app.